# In Jira, is there a way to get all the tickets that appear in a specified board/query?

Tags: jira

I'd like to be able to create a board in Jira where the filter is something along the lines of: `get me all tickets that appear on board x or board y`.

Is this possible? If so, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Because each board is driven by its own filter, just create a new filter that includes both:

```
filter in("Filter for board A","Filter for board B")
```

or

```
filter = "Filter for board A" or filter = "Filter for board B"
```

Comment: What if the owner of board x changes which filter is used on the board? I'd prefer a method that could account for this, but if that's not possible then this query will be good enough...